# install.packages("stats") fails "as ‘lib’ is unspecified"

Tags: r, lib, install.packages

I've been having trouble re-installing the package "stats" (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2) after updating to R version 4.0.0. This is what happens:

> install.packages("stats")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ju3564li/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘stats’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'

Based on other discussions on this forum, I suspect that I may have to change my repository using options(repos = "xxx"), but I haven't found any info on which repository "stats" is on.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this? Grateful for any ideas!

Comment: `stats` is part of base R, it can't be installed using `install.packages()`.  Only contributed packages can be installed that way.  The way to update `stats` is to update the R installation.

Comment: First, stats() should come loaded with base R.  Second, do other packages install for you?  If not, installing the development version of the package.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the installation and everything works fine now. Other packages also install!